# Concavity and Finiteness of a value function

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, stochastic-processes, convex-analysis, finance

I have encountered the following problem, when working trough the paper
"The condition on the Asymptotic Elasticity of Utility Functions and Optimal Investment in Incomplete Markets" by D. Kramkov and W. Schachermayer (see [link](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~schachermayer/pubs/preprnts/prpr0090.pdf)).

Let $U:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing, strictly concave and continuously differentiable function, which satisfies the Inada conditions, i.e. $$ U'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}U'(x)=\infty, \quad U'(\infty)=\lim_{x\to\infty}U'(x)=0.$$ 
Further let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq L^0_+(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be convex, solid ( $f\in\mathcal{C}$ and $0\leq g\leq f$ imply $g\in\mathcal{C}$), bounded and closed in the topology of convergence in measure. Then for x>0 define the set $\mathcal{C}(x):=x\mathcal{C}$ as well as the value function $$ u(x)=\sup_{g\in\mathcal{C}(x)}\mathbb{E}[U(g)].$$
Further assume that $u(x)<\infty$ for some $x>0$, then it is remarked in the paper that $u(x)<\infty$ for all $x>0$, as well as that $u$ is concave.

I have some problems verifying those claims. My idea was to show that $u$ is concave and conclude that in this case the assumption implies $u(x)<\infty$ for all $x>0$. However I failed to do so, as the standard approach, i.e. showing $u(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq \lambda u(x)+(1-\lambda) u(y)$, doesn't seem to work.

I would kindly appreciate some input and thoughts on the topic.

EDIT: Question is answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h_i \in C$. Note that

$\lambda E[U(x h_1)] + (1 - \lambda) E[U(y h_2)] = $

$E[\lambda U(x h_1) + (1-\lambda) U(y h_2)] \leq $

$E[U(\lambda x h_1 + (1 - \lambda) y h_2)]$

by concavity of $U$.

Now the function $h$, given by $\lambda x h_1 + (1 - \lambda) y h_2 = (\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y) h$, is a convex combination of $h_1$ and $h_2$, and is therefore in $C$.

Thus we continue the estimate:

$... = E[U((\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) h)] \leq u(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y)$.

Let $z$ be the point where $u(z)$ is finite. Let $0 < x < z = \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y < y$.

Applying $\sup_{h_i \in C}[\cdots]$ to the above inequality shows that $u(x)$ and $u(y)$ are finite. Moreover, $u$ is convex.

Comment: Thank very much for your answer.  Here are my thoughts for that the case the supremum is not assumed. If we find for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ $h_1$ such that $\mathbb{E}[U(xh_1)]+\varepsilon\geq u(x)$ and similar for $u(y)$, we could follow your reasoning and obtain the desired result. However this seems to require $u(x)<\infty$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Tsuyoi: I think it is quite clear by "solidity" of $C$ that: If $u(z) < \infty$ for some $z > 0$ then $u$ is finite on $[0, z]$. Right?

Comment: Yes, your statement should be true. This could also be seen by noting that for $g\in\mathcal{C}$ $z\mapsto\mathbb{E}[U(zg)]$ is an increasing function (since $U$ is increasing and $g$ takes positive values only), hence the function $u$ is increasing as well.

Comment: @Tsuyoi: ok, then for $x < z = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y < y$ it should be possible to show $u(y) < \infty$ along the lines of the concavity argument.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again. Then, once concavity is shown, we have $\infty > u(z)\geq \lambda u(x)+(1-\lambda)u(y)$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1)$, which implies $u(y)<\infty$. Then I still have to work out the concavity of $u$ completely.

Comment: @Tsuyoi: Question answered?

Comment: Almost, I updated my question slightly to highlight my remaining confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and pointing out my misunderstanding about your wording. I appreciate the effort you have put into this.

Comment: @Tsuyoi: alright!